# WHERE that selects ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, select

I have a query that I wish to initially call to catch all results from a database.

Then, when a combobox is updated, I wish for it to catch the columns only `WHERE column = SelectedItemFromComboBox`.

It's all done; the only thing I am missing is some way to query

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 = ALL;
```

So that I can then update it to

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 = SelectedItemFromComboBox;
```

What can I initially set the string for `SelectedItemFromComboBox`to so that I return all values?

Thanks.

Comment: Simply remove the WHERE clause : `select * from Table1;`. Don't use hacks and bad SQL just to avoid one line of code in your program.

Comment: @dystroy The question is how achieve that without building SQL on client side.

Comment: @dystroy This would not work, and will not produce bad SQL.

Comment: @SimonKiely What do you mean with "this would not work". Surely, omitting the WHERE clause would give you all rows of the table.

Comment: @Christian.K It would not allow me to restrict the returned results; however!

Comment: @SimonKiely But this is what your asking for "WHERE that selects ALL?", isn't it. Surely, you'd need to queries of course, that you invoke conditionally. One with the WHERE clause if something is selected form the combobox and one without for the "all case".

Comment: @Christian.K I guess it depends on which you consider better practice. It's probably clearer to have two distinct queries; but to combine them both into one you can potentially save on a lot of code duplication! My idea is to initally call the "WHERE that selects ALL" and then update the "ALL" so that the query is "WHERE that selects SELECTED_ITEM" - as a matter of interest; why would you consider this a bad idea? You're probably/certainly more experienced than me and I would like to learn! :)

Comment: @SimonKiely I wouldn't (necessarily) consider it a bad design idea. I was merely trying to correct the ["this would not work"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291639/where-that-selects-all#comment14854051_11291639) part. :-)

Comment: In terms of design, I'd suggest that a sparsely populated `Column1` should not exist on `Table1` at all and the `Table1` -> `ComboBox` selection relationship should be stored in another entity. I believe that leads to a single query that is efficient.

Comment: A common technique in stored procedures is to use an `if` statement to select the appropriate query, one with a `where` clause and one without.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `SelectedItemFromComboBox` to `null` and change your query to

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 = SelectedItemFromComboBox
or SelectedItemFromComboBox is null
```

Comment: It is worth noting here that this will result in a full scan, even if something is selected from the combo box.

Answer (score 3):

You can put something like the empty string into `SelectedItemFromComboBox` and modify your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE SelectedItemFromComboBox = ''
   OR Column1 = SelectedItemFromComboBox;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 = Column1
```

will get all the data

so you can use a null value

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 = isnull(some_value, Column1)
```

where some value is NULL. To do this use an empty string and then this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 = isnull(CASE WHEN some_value = '' then NULL  else some_value end)), Column1)
```

and this will return what you want

Answer (score 0):

In this condition you can set the "SelectedItemFromComboBox" to 0 and update the 
query in this way so if first condition not match its going for OR condition where 0=0 and 
returns all records for initial combobox value.

SELECT * FROM Table1

WHERE Column1 = SelectedItemFromComboBox OR 0=SelectedItemFromComboBox ;

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you are unable to modify the query and you only have control over the value going in, and you're not using parameterized queries, and you know 100% how to protect against SQL injection, then you can set `SelectedItemFromComboBox` to `'' OR 1 = 1`.  This should be extremely rare and only be needed if there's bad code that you don't have control over, and is completely a hack.