# TSQL ?: operator functionality

Tags: t-sql, constructor

I am looking for functionality similar to the C# operator ?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

I need to filter data on server side based on two parametres:

1. @CountryIDs - which is list of comma separated values, e.g. '27,28,81' - meaning CountryID 27, CountryID 28 and CountryID 81
2. @Keyword to match a customer name.

Sometimes I do not want to provide a full list of CountryIDs that should be selected, but rather I want everything selected - sort of like a "*.*"
I have created a custom function "CSV2Table_fn" that allows me to provide a list of CSV's like the CountryIDs.

```
DECLARE @CountryIDs nvarchar(4000), @Keyword nvarchar(50)
SET @CountryIDs = '25,28,81'
SET @Keyword = null


if (len(@Keyword) > 0) -- search for names matching keyword
    begin
    
        SELECT Name, CountryID FROM Company 
                WHERE CountryID IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT ItemValue FROM CSV2Table_fn(
                        ISNULL((SELECT 
                            CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ItemValue FROM CSV2Table_fn(@CountryIDs,',')) t) > 0   THEN @CountryIDs
                            ELSE null
                            END
                    ),CountryID),',')
            )
            AND Name LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'      
            
    end
else -- no keyword provided
    begin
        
        SELECT Name, CountryID FROM Company 
        WHERE CountryID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ItemValue FROM CSV2Table_fn(
            ISNULL((SELECT 
                        CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ItemValue FROM CSV2Table_fn(@CountryIDs,',')) t) > 0   THEN @CountryIDs
                        ELSE null
                        END
                ),CountryID),',')
        )
                end
```

- Edit: The code now works as supposed to. However this is not very clean, and could probably be optimized.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291639/where-that-selects-all for advice to not do that.

Comment: The @CountryIDs variable is not coming from client side, so I don't believe it should be an issue?

Comment: What you currently have is suggested as the correct solution in that question, as opposed to attempts to write a single `where`.

Comment: No sure I follow you; I can not pass in a null value for the @CountryIDs to select everything and this is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I can change the `SELECT DISTINCT...` to something like

 `ISNULL((SELECT DISTINCT ItemValue FROM CSV2Table_fn(@CountryIDs,',')),CountryID)` 

But that only works if I only supply one CountryID - not multiple. This change also works with null value, but the problem still remains with multiple countryids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow for null and CSVs like '123,456,789' to be passed in as value for @CountryIDs I used this:

```
 SELECT Name, CountryID FROM Company  
    WHERE CountryID IN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT ItemValue FROM CSV2Table_fn( 
        ISNULL((SELECT  
                    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ItemValue FROM CSV2Table_fn(@CountryIDs,',')) t) > 0   THEN @CountryIDs 
                    ELSE null 
                    END 
            ),CountryID),',') 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this:

```
SELECT Name, CountryID 
FROM   Company 
WHERE  CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(varchar(100), CountryID) + ',', ',' + ISNULL(@CountryIDs, CONVERT(varchar(100), CountryID)) + ',') > 0
AND    Name LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Keyword, '') + '%'
```

** edited to be a bit simpler and handle null @CountryIDs param.

Comment: This will work if null is _not_ supplied. I managed to find a fix to my original code. I have added a fix to the code you supplied as well.

`SELECT Name, CountryID  
FROM   Company  
WHERE  CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(CountryID as nvarchar) + ',', ',' + @CountryIDs + ',') > 0 
AND    (Name LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' OR @Keyword IS NULL)`

Comment: If NULL is not supplied as what? The CountryID parameter, the Keyword parameter, or as a value in the column? If you want to select all CountryIDs in some cases, then use something like `WHERE (CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(CountryID as nvarchar) + ',', ',' + @CountryIDs + ',') > 0 OR @CountryIDs IS NULL) AND    (Name LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' OR @Keyword IS NULL)`. I'm not 100% sure I follow the requirement here, though.

Comment: If I want to select everything (no filtering using WHERE on CountryID), I doing something like SET @CountryIDs = null. This will not work on your first piece of code (have not tested your second piece of code)... Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: You solution is simpler - I have chosen that :) Thanks for the help.